# Using Python to create a popup that changes an object based on the input

Tags: python

So I found this example from another answer here. I'm new to programing and don't fully understand how it all flows. I've only used "def execute" to run stuff. I would like to create a class that creates a popup menu. I would like the popup to change the selected object when I adjust variable within it (without hitting okay). Is it even possible? I defined "athing" below to test. I want it to go to edit mode, select everything and divide. It says it can't modify blend data in this state. Thank you for the help.

```
class DialogOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
bl_idname = "object.dialog_operator"
bl_label = "Simple Dialog Operator"

my_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Some Floating Point")
my_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Toggle Option")
my_string = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="String Value")

def execute(self, context):
    message = "Popup Values: %f, %d, '%s'" % \
        (self.my_float, self.my_bool, self.my_string)
    self.report({'INFO'}, message)
    return {'FINISHED'}

def check(self, context):
    return True

def athing(self, context):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')  
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

    #SUBDIVED VIA "subs" INPUT
    bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(smoothness=0)
    return {'FINISHED'}

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.prop(self, "my_bool")
    if self.my_bool:
        layout.label("It's TRUE")
        layout.prop(self, "my_string")
        self.athing(self)

def invoke(self, context, event):
    wm = context.window_manager
    return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use an update method on a property.**

Give that whole "athing" thing away. You CANNOT use draw methods to run code to update objects. (The you cannot modify blenddata in this state error)

You can define a button to click that calls an operator, or a property that when changed runs an update. .. which I believe is what you want update method on properties Example below, on changing `my_bool` if True will call the `athing(self, context)` method. `self` will be a reference tot the operator.

```
import bpy
class DialogOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.dialog_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Dialog Operator"

    def athing(self, context):
        if self.my_bool:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')  
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(smoothness=0)
        return None

    my_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Some Floating Point")
    my_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Toggle Option", update=athing)
    my_string = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="String Value")

    def execute(self, context):
        message = "Popup Values: %f, %d, '%s'" % \
            (self.my_float, self.my_bool, self.my_string)
        self.report({'INFO'}, message)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def check(self, context):
        return True

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "my_bool")


    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

bpy.utils.register_class(DialogOperator)
# test call
bpy.ops.object.dialog_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: Thank you batFINGER! This has been tormenting me for so long. I understand this so much better now. :)