# how to use poll in object and edit mode?

Tags: python

I want to assure in my add-on that the user has selected some edges.

I use poll to do so, but i got this error here:

```
ops.py", line 113, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.object.mode_set" error, can't modify blend data in this state (drawing/rendering)
```

I understood it in that way, that i must not change object/edit mode in a poll statement, i hope this is right?

Here is my poll def:

```
  @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        
        oldMode = getMode(context)
            
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm.from_mesh(context.active_object.data)
    
        # check whether edges are selected
        noOfSelectedEdges = len([ e for e in bm.edges if e.select])
        WM_OT_dialogop.edges = noOfSelectedEdges
        
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=oldMode) 
        
        if noOfSelectedEdges == 0:
            print("my error was set")
            myError = "Please select edges"
        else:
            print("my error was cleared")
            myError = ""
            
        return True # errors will be shown as text
```

And i think i need to be in object mode to get the selected edges that way.

What i want is to get the selected edges in edit and in object mode so the user don't have to be in a special mode.
Is that possible, and if yes, how?
Maybe i am on a total wrong way...i am open for better/cleaner ways!

Comment: Seems to be the famous _change data from draw method error_. See batFINGERs answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92213/using-python-to-create-a-popup-that-changes-an-object-based-on-the-input

Comment: @relaxed: Thank you very much, exactly was i was searching for!